# Select (keyword) from table phpmyadmin using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, select, phpmyadmin, sql-like

Following on from my last question:

I am now using the statement:

```
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
    }


      SELECT name, url FROM table WHERE species LIKE '%$url%'
```

`species` could have content likes `"Brown & Rainbow Trout, Pike"`

however my url for say Brown Trout is : `/fishing/browntrout/`

This basically prevents the statement above from returning any results.

Clearly it works fine for say : `/fishing/pike/` just not for the fish that have 2 names.

Whats the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Save it as `Brown Trout, Rainbow Trout, & Pike`?

Comment: Yeah this could be a solution although i am trying to avoid this as the space i have on the page which displays 'species' is not large enough to hold alot of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the url `/fishing/brown_trout/` instead.  Then try something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) { // "brown_trout"
    $url = str_replace('_', '%', $_GET['url']); // "brown%trout"
}

SELECT name, url FROM table WHERE species LIKE '%$url%'
```

This will make the query:

```
SELECT name, url FROM table WHERE species LIKE '%brown%trout%'
```

Which should work.

Comment: This seems to work correctly however, I seem to get different results if the url is '/brown/' instead of '/brown_trout/'

there is no other species with 'brown' in its name. clearly there are other 'trout' could this be causing an issue? as i expected to get the same results with brown and brown trout